# Aerating wine on shabbos

Tags: shabbat, grapes-wine

Is it permissible to use an aerator (non battery operated) on shabbos?

What about a decanter?

Comment: Is there a reason you think it could be an issue?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Ben and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is it permissible to use an aerator (non battery operated) on Shabbos?

Since the wine is drinkable without aeration (for us non-connoisseurs) adding air should not be an issue. Besides, we do not find that adding ingredients is an issue on Shabbos unless it changes the consistency of the mixure.

Q: What about a decanter?

Search for "Shabbos decanter" and you will find that it's a very popular way to serve wine on Shabbos and skirts the issue of Toveling the wine bottle.

Comment: "skirts the issue of toveling the wine bottle", explain yourself please

Comment: @Dude, we normally require toveling dishes before using them. Wine bottles are not toiveled. We rely on opinions that since we didn't fill it, we don't have to empty it but can use it until it's empty. But with Kidush wine there's a concept of pouring back some of the wine from the evening Kidush for the morning, and from the morning for Havdolo. (Don't do this - you will render the wine unfit if you don't know the Halachot). Pouring wine back means that you are now using a non-toiveled bottle. A decanter solves this.

Comment: Interesting. I've never poured wine back into a bottle but keep some my in my cup and put it in the fridge from Kiddush to Kiddush until havdalah

Answer (score 0):

There is no Melacha involved that I can see. Oneg Shabbos would say therefore OK.

Comment: Are you good at spotting melachos? None us here know if you are or not.